# Configure STP in WAN Bridge

Tags: networking, firewall, pfsense, stp

Hardware:

```
2 pFsense Box
1 Switch Dlink DGS-3324SR
```

I need to configure a STP into my network because i'm trying to set a wan redundant bridge for a web server. (Take a look to my Network Diagram)
So i need to prevent the loops (Broadcast Storms) into my switch.

Someone can give me example of how to configure stp?
Thanks.
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9kEA.png)

Comment: You probably don't need spanning tree for this. You would want to configure our PFSense firewalls in an HA cluster with one node being active and the other as standby. This solves multiple problems as the HA configuration would keep the firewall configurations in synch and would manage the failover from active to the standby as needed.

Comment: Yo mean to use CARP in all members interfaces of each firewalls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another switch on the WAN side and to configure CARP on both the public side and the private side with a floating IP.  You don't need to worry about STP.

Here are [some instructions](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Configuring_pfSense_Hardware_Redundancy_%28CARP%29) on how to configure it.